# There are three options for CPU mining Monero on a pool. Which one is best?

Tags: cpu-mining

I see Claymore's CPU miner, Wolf's CPU miner, and YAM. How do I know which one to choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try them and see? Of the three [Wolf's CPU miner](https://github.com/OhGodAPet/cpuminer-multi) is the only open source option; the other two, [claymore](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=647251.0) and [yam](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=660758.0) are closed source and do "fee mining" for the creator, sending a few percent of the hashes to the creator's pool and address of choice. I don't think there's been a really objective comparison of the three, especially across a range of processors. The best way to see would probably be to use each to mine on a largeish pool for a day or three using each of them when difficulty is relatively flat and see which gives the largest payout.

Edit: there is also now the open source [xmr-stak miner](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu), which I believe has a default donation to dev that can be disabled.

Comment: Can you update answer with links towards mentioned tools?

Comment: Added links and new miner.